# setting the objectForKey with a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I am building an app where I need to change some helpful information based on what stage the user is at:

I used strings labeled Stage1 ... Stage7 in the dictionary and I want to display the helpful info from each Stage wen the user moves the slider.

```
NSDictionary *foodInfo = [foodArray objectAtIndex:row];

NSInteger numberLookup = lroundf([stageSlider value]);
NSString* stageText = @"Stage";
stageText = [stageText stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i", numberLookup];

NSNumber *helps = [foodInfo objectForKey:@"Stage1"]; // Need stageText string instead "Stage1" shown?
notesLabel.text = helps;
```

Currently I display the "Stage1" text no matter where the slider is positioned and I have verified that "stageText" is incrementing/decrementing just fine.

How do I put the stageText string in instead of the text string shown?

Thanks for the help.

padapa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that ? `NSNumber *helps = [foodInfo objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"stage%d",numberLookup]];`

Comment: Thanks malinois, that works and shortens up the code too :) nice!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumber *helps = [foodInfo objectForKey:stageText];
```

Comment: I like the simplicity, but I get this error: 'stagetText' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: @padapa: but stageText is defined only a couple of lines above.  Your comment has a typo in it, perhaps the same typo  is in your code: 'stage**t**Text' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: yeah, the comment does have a typo ... I'll doubble check the code... (just kidding with this typo)